# Two attributes of the same entity

Tags: hibernate

I have two entities

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Id
    private Long Id;

    //attributes of A
}

@Entity
class B {  
    xxx
    private A instanceOfA_1;

    xxx
    private A instanceOfA_2;
}
```

As you see, I have two attributes of type A in class B.

How would you annotate these two attributes in Hibernate ?
In the end, in the database, I expect to find two columns in the table B, each column containing the key id in table A.

I guess this is a simple ORM question, but I didn't manage to get it alone...

---

EDIT : after the response above, you suggest that I do the following ?

```
@Entity
class A {
  @Id
  private Long Id;  
  //attributes of A
}

@Entity
class B {
@ManyToOne
private A instanceOfA_1;
@ManyToOne
private A instanceOfA_2;
}
```

This will create the following tables ?

```
Table A
  id
  attributes

Table B
  a_id_1
  a_id_2
```

How do I specify the name of the columns in table B (i.e. a_id_1 and a_id_2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather typical situation, each of them should be annotated with [@ManyToOne](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html). [@OneToOne](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) should be used if per relation only one B can be related to given A. If database schema is generated from the entities, with @OneToOne there will be unique constraint in foreign key.

[@JoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) can be used to specify name of the foreign key column:

```
 @JoinColumn(name="preferred_column_name")
```

Comment: Thanks JB, added to answer. user1446127, instructions and link to @JoinColumn documentation added.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@Entity
class A {
   @Id
   private Long Id;  
}

@Entity
class B {
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="A_1")
   private A instanceOfA_1;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="A_2")
   private A instanceOfA_2;
}
```